# CSS: make dropdown submenu appear below parent <ul> <li>

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a CSS dropdown menu. The problem is that all child nodes in the ul li tree appear on the same row, instead of below the parent. How do I make the subcategories appear BELOW the parent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `display:block; float: left;position: relative;` on the `li` to establish a containing block and then `position:absolute; top:100%; left:0;` on the sub-menu `ul` to position it with respect to its containing block.

Comment: I just did that, you can see the result.. still not what's supposed to happen

Comment: Add `display:block; float: left;` to the `li` and it will work.

Comment: which li should I add it to ?

Comment: @DreamWave To the same one that you added `position: relative`, the one that holds the submenu. I did it with firebug and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css to position the submenu.

```
ul li {
    position: relative;
}

ul li ul.sub {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I just did that, you can see the result.. still not what's supposed to happen

Answer (score 1):

Your main menu items need to have a positioning context, probably relative. Then, for the child menu, set the positioning to absolute, set left to 0 and top to 100%. That should do the trick.

Comment: I just did that, you can see the result.. still not what's supposed to happen