# CSS dropdown menu subitem positioning

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm having an issue where my dropdown is always on the left. I need to have it so it's directly under each menu item.

I tried playing around with the positioning because the absolute of the subitems is why it's going on the left all the time. But putting `position: relative` on `subitem` breaks the menu completely on hover.

Demo of issue: https://jsfiddle.net/dsngpsxb/2/

Code below:

HTML:

```
<nav class="main-navigation">
    <ul>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">item</a>
          <ul class="subitem">
            <li>subitem</li>
            <li>subitem</li>
            <li>subitem</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">item</a>
          <ul class="subitem">
            <li>subitem</li>
            <li>subitem</li>
            <li>subitem</li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">item</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">item</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">item</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">item</a></li>
      <li class="item"><a href="#">item</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

SCSS/SASS:

```
.main-navigation {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 18px;
    .item {
      display: inline;
      padding-right: 43px;
      font-size: 13px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      &:hover ul {
        display: block;
      }
    }
  }
}

.subitem {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  li {
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

Please note that I did indeed do research here and found several questions on SO that explain my problem and I tried all accepted answers but none work.

I have included each example with a corresponding JSfiddle example below:

[Dropdown menu appearing not below parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22402346/dropdown-menu-appearing-not-below-parent)

adding `position: relative` to my subitem completely breaks menu: https://jsfiddle.net/mtp2cg7c/2/

[CSS: make dropdown submenu appear below parent <ul> <li>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4333372/css-make-dropdown-submenu-appear-below-parent-ul-li?rq=1)

block display, relative positioning and a left float on my `<li>` with absolute positioning, 100% top and left: 0 on my `<ul>` "smashes" all the items togther: https://jsfiddle.net/9s9Lmr1h/4/

[CSS dropdown menu element moving to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562390/css-dropdown-menu-element-moving-to-left)

In the fiddle attached I noted that the global container as a property of `clear: both;` - I tried that in conjunction with floats and positioning. All sub items still float to the left: https://jsfiddle.net/3x3krdsd/1/

Is my `<nav>` tag to blame? I can't find anything that suggests this tag alters behavior of these rules: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `position: relative;` to your `.item` and `left: 0;` to your `.subitem`.

This will make the sub-item position itself relative to the parent item, which should give you the result you want: https://jsfiddle.net/58sb3rL4/